# OnPostExecute doesn't call after doInBackground Sucess

Tags: java, android, performance, android-asynctask

I have a search of data im my android app and debug by the console, when I check the console I see the `doInBackground` works fine, but after it doesn't call `onPostExecute`. I don't know because of what, someone can help ?

```
   protected List<Recipe> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            List<Recipe> recipes=RecipeService.getRecipes(context,"a");
            if(recipes != null) android.util.Log.i(TAG,"encontrados");
            return recipes;
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            android.util.Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage(),e);
            android.util.Log.i(TAG,"ta akiiiiii");
            com.android.utils.AndroidUtils.AlertDialog(context,R.string.name_io);
        }finally{
            progresso.dismiss();
        }
        return null;
    }


//Update a view


protected void OnPostExecute(List<Recipe> recipes) {
    android.util.Log.i(TAG,"are here");
    for (Recipe recipe : recipes) {
        android.util.Log.i(TAG,"Carro: "+recipe.name);
    }
}
```

The log are here never execute, please have some wrong ? the `try` of `doInBackground` works.

Answer (score 1):

Its `onPostExecute()`, not `OnPostExecute()`. Use small letter `o` in `onPostExecute()`.

Replace your code with this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Recipe> recipes) {
    android.util.Log.i(TAG,"are here");
    for (Recipe recipe : recipes) {
        android.util.Log.i(TAG,"Carro: "+recipe.name);
    }
}
```

always try to add `@Override` annotation if you are trying to override a method. This way you will know if you wrote method signature correctly or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is capitalised, breaking java conventions. The actual method is called `onPostExecute()`. Because the name is different, you have not actually overriden the method. This sort of thing is why the `@Override` annotation is so useful- it would have given you a compile error here if you used it.